# Why does direct passage of string to printf correctly works?

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf

I know that in C both of these works:

```
char* string = "foo";
printf("string value: %s", string);
```

and more simply:

```
printf("string value: %s", "foo");
```

But I was asking myself why.

I know that `%s` identifier expects the argument to be a char*, and `string` actually is (and it will be the same with an array of characters, because this two datatypes are pretty the same in C)

but when I pass directly a string to printf shouldn't it be different? I mean `"foo"` is not a pointer anymore... Right?.

Comment: I think it is a `char*` like you explained before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"foo"` is string literal. It represents an unnamed array object with static storage duration of type `char[4]` (that is, *without* `const` qualifier), that is passed to function by value, just as it would be with any "normal" array.

Even though the array is not `const`, you are not allowed to *modify* its values. Such modification results in undefined behavior:

```
char* string = "foo";
string[0] = 'b'; // wrong, this invokes UB
```

The array has four elements, because of trailing *null character* `'\0'`, sometimes reffered as `NUL` character. Please don't confuse it with `NULL`, which is a different thing. The purpose of that character is to terminate given string literal.

The function's parameter receives pointer to `char`, as array object is *converted* into pointer to array's first element (i.e. pointer to first character in array). To be precise, not the whole pointer is passed, only the address (i.e. the value of the pointer) it holds.

Answer (score 6):

The string constant `"foo"` has type `char []`.  When passed to a function, the array decays to a pointer, i.e. `char *`.  So you can pass it to a function that expects the same.

For the same reason, you can also pass a variable of this type:

```
char string[4] = "foo";
printf("string value: %s", string);
```

Comment: Wrong, that isn't the type of a string literal.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for the clarification.  Edited.

Comment: I think it is more like `const char[4]`.

Comment: The string literal has type `char[4]`  , it is not `const`

Comment: @M.M Thanks for the clarification.  Fixed.

Comment: @juanchopanza: That's C++.  In C, string literals have type "array of `char`".

Answer (score 1):

In C, all strings are null-terminating char[] so your example will interact in the same exact way.

The ISO C standard, section 7.1.1, defines a string this way:

> A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and
>   including the first null character.

Answer (score 0):

What `printf()` gets, *is* a pointer:

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, 6.5.2.2 – 4:

> An argument may be an expression of any object type. In preparing for the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument.81)
>
> 81) A parameter declared to have array or function type is adjusted to have a pointer type as described in 6.9.1.

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, 6.9.1 – 10:

> On entry to the function, the size expressions of each variably modified parameter are evaluated and the value of each argument expression is converted to the type of the corresponding parameter as if by assignment. (**Array expressions and function designators as arguments were converted to pointers before the call.**)

Comment: Your quotes are about parameter types, not arguments. The corresponding parameter type for `printf` is `...` (ellipsis), not an array parameter and not a variably modified parameter.

Comment: 6.3.2.1/3 (C11 numbering) is the section describing conversion of array to pointer, in arguments and elsewhere

Comment: No, my first quote is about the parameter types. And my second quote is about passing arguments respecting the parameter type.

Answer (score -1):

`"foo"`, in the end, is a pointer literal pointing to a statically allocated 4-byte memory region (likely marked read-only) that is initialized with the content: 'f'. 'o', 'o', '\0'.